# matching nullptr by T *

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, metaprogramming, generic-programming

Using `boost::variant` of pointers to AST nodes, which can contain value of special type `std::nullptr_t`, indicating emptiness, I faced the problem: generic visitors of the form `[] (auto /* const */ * p) { /* use p */; }` or of the form:

```
struct V
{
    template< typename T >
    void operator () (T /* const */ * p)
    { /* use p */; }
};
```

can't deal with value of `std::nullptr_t` type.

There is a plenty of workarounds one can imagine, but the question rising: is there good explanation why there no (very likely highly restricted) `decltype(*nullptr)` type in the language (`*nullptr` is ill-formed and `std::remove_pointer_t< std::nullptr_t >` is `std::nullptr_t` in *libc++*)? Are there theoretical reasons for this?

Comment: "std::nullptr_t is the type of the null pointer literal, nullptr. It is a distinct type that is not itself a pointer type or a pointer to member type." So `std::remove_pointer_t` is redundant.

Comment: Also, I think the point of making `nullptr_t` a type was so that one could write overloads and specializations for it, as so many people use null values as flags.

Comment: There are [abominable function types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html), but there no instances of such types in the language. Type of dereferenced nullptr is similar to them on my mind in this respect.

Comment: @AndyG in generic code I often just want to separate pointers and forward them further.

Comment: [std::is_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) and [std::is_null_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_null_pointer) say that `std::is_pointer< std::nullptr_t >::value` should be `false`. Are you sure about your static assertion?

Comment: @TBBle sorry, no. My mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there good explanation why there no (very likely highly restricted) decltype(*nullptr) type in the language (*nullptr is ill-formed and std::remove_pointer_t< std::nullptr_t > is std::nullptr_t in libc++)? Are there theoretical reasons for this?

I think to answer this question, we must look at [N1601](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1601.pdf) proposed by Herb Sutter and Bjarne Stroustrup.

A couple sections stand out to me, particularly

4.10 [conv.ptr]

> A null pointer constant or an object of type nullptr_t can be converted to a 
>   pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type

and 4.11 [conv.mem]:

> A null pointer constant (4.10) or an object of type nullptr_t (4.10) can be converted to a pointer
>   to member type; the result is the null member pointer value of that type

So if the result of passing a `nullptr` or `nullptr_t` is a null pointer of the given pointer type, then it makes sense that dereferencing it (e.g., via `decltype(*nullptr)` would be the same as dereferencing any other kind of null pointer. (in the specific case of `delctype(*nullptr)` I believe it's akin to dereferencing a null `void*`). That is, you shouldn't do it.

> std::remove_pointer_t< std::nullptr_t > is std::nullptr_t

The reason this is true is easy enough, but the WHY is harder to get at.

#### The reason:

> [std::nullptr_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) is the type of the null pointer literal, nullptr. It is a distinct type that is not itself a pointer type or a pointer to member type.

Given that, it makes sense that `std::remove_pointer_t` would have no effect because `nullptr_t` is not a pointer type.

#### The why

In N1601, Sutter and Stroustrup said

> nullptr_t is not a reserved word. It is a typedef (as its _t typedef indicates) for decltype(nullptr) defined in <cstddef>. We do not expect to see much direct use of nullptr_t in real programs.

Indeed this is what actually seems to have happened. Clang 3.9.0, for example has the following in stddef.h:

```
namespace std { typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t; }
using ::std::nullptr_t;
```

(and also they were right about not much `nullptr_t` appearing in many programs).

This still doesn't explain *WHY* it is defined as such. To do that, I think we need to go back in time a little farther to [N1488](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1488.pdf), also by Sutter and Stroustrup where they said:

> This use of the value `0` to mean different things (a pointer constant and an `int`) in C++ has caused
>   problems since at least 1985 in teaching, learning, and using C++. In particular:
>
> - Distinguishing between null and zero. The null pointer and an integer `0` cannot be distinguished
>     well for overload resolution. For example, given two overloaded functions `f(int)` and `f(char*)`,
>     the call `f(0)` unambiguously resolves to `f(int)`. There is no way to write a call to `f(char*)` with a 
>     null pointer value without writing an explicit cast (i.e., `f((char*)0)`) or using a named variable.
>     Note that this implies that today’s null pointer, `0`, has no utterable type.
> - Naming null. Further, programmers have often requested that the null pointer constant have a
>     name (rather than just `0`). This is one reason why the macro `NULL` exists, although that macro is
>     insufficient. (If the null pointer constant had a type-safe name, this would also solve the
>     previous problem as it could be distinguished from the integer `0` for overload resolution and
>     some error detection.)

Which I think explains the why pretty well; programmers needed a way to distinguish between pointers and integer values for in overloads, and since `NULL` is generally defined as `0`, which is usually interpreted as an integer type, there was no easy way to force overload resolution to select the pointer overload. Now that we have `nullptr`, we can distinguish between pointer and non-pointer types which avoids this issue altogether.